# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/19014).

Comment: Trivia note - this post ID is 19014, and the ID of the previous ads thread was 11920. That means that in the span of a bit over a year (rather close to 13 months, really), over 7000 posts have been made to the Mathematics Meta site. That's the highest amount in that time span on the network, towering over Ask Ubuntu's ~4600 sitting in second place.

Comment: Some ideas: [MathEducators.SE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), [HSM.SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/), [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: (Re: Trivia note) That sounds quite sad, actually...

Comment: @GrigoryM Depends on how you look at it. There are sad SE sites with sad inactive metas where nobody cares about anything.

Answer (score 84):

[image: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: To quote Brian M. Scott: «This one’s so useful that I even donate a little to them each year» (me too).

Answer (score 81):

[image: Detexify]

Comment: This is always useful in a bind and if you just can't remember that one symbol. Brilliant for people learning TeX, like me! 
The ad could be improved a bit though.

Comment: The ad could be made a lot better; without your comment @BenjaminR , I wouldn't have understood the ad.

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar I only knew what it was because I had visited the site before through a description and link on TeX.SE...

Answer (score 64):

[image: arXiv.org]

Comment: maybe $1\,000\,000$ would look more impressive?.. (it's fine anyway, though)

Comment: Should this be changed to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6p4Ey.jpg)

Comment: Thank you! Come to think of it, either version looks OK.

Comment: I think this one looks better.

Answer (score 53):

[image: GeoGebra]

Answer (score 51):

[image: Wolfram Alpha]

Comment: Each year there are debates about advertising WolframAlpha (Wolfram sells commercial software etc.) — but I still think it's tremendously useful.

Comment: (To quote Dominic Michaelis in previous discussion: «I think wolframalpha isn't mainly a CAS, but something special, because of you don't need to know a bit of syntax to use it while for most CAS you need to know the correct syntax. Furthermore the basic functions of wolframalpha are free»)

Comment: One more quote from prev. discussions: «I have no doubt that informing users about Wolfram Alpha will decrease the number of very elementary algebra/calculus questions asked here, and increase the quality of the ones that still are»

Comment: I would vote for an add the wolfram Mathworld site http://mathworld.wolfram.com/  can e add that one instead?

Answer (score 50):

[image: MIT OCW]

Answer (score 50):

[image: ProofWiki - online compendium of mathematical proofs.]

Comment: Copy of [last year's version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11928/43351).

Answer (score 42):

[image: SageMath]

Comment: Copy of [last year's version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11949/54806).

Answer (score 27):

[image: HSM]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all we have at the moment, though myself or another HSM user may try to update the image.

Comment: +1 provisionally with the expectation of improvement... maybe use something related to [Archimedes](http://archimedespalimpsest.org/about/history/archimedes.php), who represents both science and mathematics.

Comment: @Behaviour We almost named our chatroom after him ("Archimedes Circle"), though it lost to "On the Shoulders of Giants". Thanks for the support. We really need this ad to do well.

Comment: @pizza I have a concept image based on your suggestion. We'll do some tweaking, but this is what we have at the moment.

Comment: I was really happy to see this just now in mathematics.SE. I suppose the alignment on the text box on the bottom could be cleaner; less excess space, and so forth. In any case, the picture is quite distinctive. It pleased me to see it.

Comment: Who is the guy on the portrait?

Comment: @becko The painting is "[Archimedes Thoughtful](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Domenico-Fetti_Archimedes_1620.jpg)", by Domenico Fetti (1620).

Answer (score 27):

[image: Current Mathematics bounties]

Comment: Copy of last year's version. Note that it works perfectly despite different size (and obviously not being hosted on imgur).

Comment: Because of the great number of questions on Math.SE the bounty system plays a quite important role, allowing to highlight interesting questions. Hope that this ad makes bounty system more visible & effective.

Comment: Last year anorton suggested that someone 'should write a similar script but with a theme more conducive to the MSE theme'. It's not that important (IMHO) but would be nice, indeed.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Comment: Per [request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015/19164#comment69854_19127); version from TeX.SE community-ads [thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5876/)

Comment: I think "by writeLaTeX" should be removed. It's simply a relaunching of that service, not a new product.

Comment: @MikeMiller But without "by writeLaTeX" the ad would look like a new product, and the continuity of transition would be lost.

Comment: Awesome tool. I write all my tests here, and have been doing so since before the name transition.

Comment: The old name made more sense.

Answer (score 26):

[image: A beautiful, free online graphing calculator]

Comment: Copy of [last year's version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014/12168#12168).

Comment: I think the font of the subtitle should be better. It definitely does not look beautiful and does not help convert. Desmos is such an awesome tool, it deserves a beautiful ad.

Comment: I totally agree on the graphic quality. I spliced this thing together last year in Mathematica using the graphic I could find on the internet because Mathematica was all I had. While it conforms to our community ad requirements, it would be nice to see something better that conforms. Thanks for putting it back up, I did not notice until now; terribly busy. Desmos deserves better. Initially, I thought I would email Desmos around Christmas and have them make us something that conforms, but the issue just escaped my time. Any improvements here would be very appreciated by all no doubt.

Comment: I used this graphing calculator and loved it very much. Its been a great help with my ideas. I hope Desmos will someday be as powerful as Python. I hope they make an even better ad next time.

Answer (score 25):

[image: StackEdit]

Comment: The light grey text is hard to read and detracts from the message. If I didn't know markdown, "*smart*" would just look like wasted pixels. I suggest dropping the "*", bringing the grey text up to full black and perhaps softening the grey text with a lighter font weight.

The image did catch my eye.

Answer (score 21):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Copied from my submission for 2014 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014/11926#11926

Answer (score 13):

[image: AMS Graduate Student Blog - Read and write about topics that matter to you.]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11937/1761

Answer (score 4):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Comment: Preliminary image; [meta discussion here](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174/community-ads-to-use-in-other-sites).

Comment: remove the border?

Comment: @Reg no, the border must exist as the question states.

Comment: My bad, @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M

Answer (score 3):

[image: An open source graphing software]

Comment: Image from http://www.padowan.dk/graph/Graph.png.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: is it possible to view the list of (say, latest) reviews on this site? (I've been trying to find at least one review for 10 minutes...)

Comment: @GrigoryM There is only 1 review at present: see http://arxitics.com/reviews/1 for an example and testing. The list of reviews will be found here http://arxitics.com/reviews (this section is still under development). Any registered users with at least 10 reputation can post reviews. We need more users!

Comment: A whopping eight months later, there's still only one review!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry for that! The majority of our users are graduate students, who do not show much interests in writing reviews. The website is actively maintained and we would like to attract more experts.

Answer (score -8):

[image: Plot beautiful math graphs in 3D]

Comment: any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Very unclear what this is for. Add some text?

Comment: It's for a software that plots math equations in 3D. I figured the images make it clear what it does. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: But is it free? Programmed?  Etc

Comment: It is free (paid versions are also available but the free edition is more than enough for most users). No programming required, you can plot a high quality 3d graph of an equation within seconds without any prior knowledge.

Comment: that is the sort of information you need in the picture

Comment: Thank you. I will add those information to the ad.

Answer (score -19):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Again, I recall that Maths tends to have a lot of other ads that deserve much better prominence.

Comment: Note concerning this post: we are in a friendly competition with other SE sites such as [Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6841/254361) and [Unix & Linux](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3312/90255).

Comment: I never quite understand why this post gets so downvoted. I do not think I would know about the twitter account if it were not for it tenaciously appearing in this thread every year, despite its prior record of downvotes.

Comment: @user1729 The algorithm the TwitterBot uses to select Questions tends to select the truly horrible more than the truly great. If you're trying to promote your site, it's probably best not to lead with the Questions TwitterBot selects.